# Help with function template syntax

Tags: esp32

I am trying to understand the following code snippet from the Espressif OTABasic example for the ESP32 wireless/BT module (see [this repository](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/ArduinoOTA/examples/BasicOTA/BasicOTA.ino) for the full code).

```
 ArduinoOTA
.onStart([]() {
  String type;
  if (ArduinoOTA.getCommand() == U_FLASH)
    type = "sketch";
  else // U_SPIFFS
    type = "filesystem";

  // NOTE: if updating SPIFFS this would be the place to unmount SPIFFS using SPIFFS.end()
  Serial.println("Start updating " + type);
})
.onEnd([]() {
  Serial.println("\nEnd");
})
.onProgress([](unsigned int progress, unsigned int total) {
  Serial.printf("Progress: %u%%\r", (progress / (total / 100)));
})
.onError([](ota_error_t error) {
  Serial.printf("Error[%u]: ", error);
  if (error == OTA_AUTH_ERROR) Serial.println("Auth Failed");
  else if (error == OTA_BEGIN_ERROR) Serial.println("Begin Failed");
  else if (error == OTA_CONNECT_ERROR) Serial.println("Connect Failed");
  else if (error == OTA_RECEIVE_ERROR) Serial.println("Receive Failed");
  else if (error == OTA_END_ERROR) Serial.println("End Failed");
});
```

The initial 'ArduinoOTA' looks kinda like an implied 'with ArduinoOTA' statement, but I can't find anything like that in the reference documents.  I know it has something to do with the way the function templates in 'ArduinoOTA.h', but it's beyond me to untangle the syntax.

May I buy a clue, please?

TIA,

Frank

Thanks to all for the clues; I'm an old-time c/c++ programmer, but must have slept through the 'lambda function' class ;-).

To help my somewhat calcified brain, is it functionally equivalent (if more clunky) to write the above snippet as shown below with the handler functions 'unchained'?

```
    ArduinoOTA.onStart
([]() //lambda function 
    { 
        String type;
        if (ArduinoOTA.getCommand() == U_FLASH)
            type = "sketch";
        else // U_SPIFFS
            type = "filesystem";

        // NOTE: if updating SPIFFS this would be the place to unmount SPIFFS using SPIFFS.end()
        Serial.println("Start updating " + type);
    }
);

ArduinoOTA.onEnd
([]() //lambda function
    {
        Serial.println("\nEnd");
    }
);

ArduinoOTA.onProgress
([](unsigned int progress, unsigned int total) //lambda func with arguments 
    {
        Serial.printf("Progress: %u%%\r", (progress / (total / 100)));
    }
);

ArduinoOTA.onError
([](ota_error_t error) //lambda func with arguments
    {
        Serial.printf("Error[%u]: ", error);
        if (error == OTA_AUTH_ERROR) Serial.println("Auth Failed");
        else if (error == OTA_BEGIN_ERROR) Serial.println("Begin Failed");
        else if (error == OTA_CONNECT_ERROR) Serial.println("Connect Failed");
        else if (error == OTA_RECEIVE_ERROR) Serial.println("Receive Failed");
        else if (error == OTA_END_ERROR) Serial.println("End Failed");
    }
);
```

TIA,

Frank

Answer (score 2):

This is called (by me, anyway) "method chaining".

It's nothing special, really.  ArduinoOTA is just an instance of the class ArduinoOTAClass.

Each method of that class does what it needs to do, then returns a reference to the object that the method is within.  Which means that you can then call a method on that returned reference ... and so on.

All the rest of it is "lambda" functions - that is, functions that are embedded within the parameters of the functions being called.

The basic result is something like:

```
A.foo().bar().baz();
```

Where A.foo() returns A. A.bar() returns A. A.baz() returns A.

You can do the same with:

```
A.foo();
A.bar();
A.baz();
```

Comment: that snipet looks like a multiple event handler declaration or multiple event handler overloading

Comment: @jsotola It's just passing anonymous ("lambda") functions as parameters to simple methods which then store those functions as as pointers and return the object again. Nothing magic about it, and no overloading or anything like that.

Comment: i learn something new every day ... thank you